# Minesweeper using Tkinter

Tags: python, game, tkinter, minesweeper

So, I have completed a Minesweeper program in Python using Tkinter.
A few questions:

1. I feel I should convert this to Object-Oriented Programming. Any starting tips?
2. Expanding on the above, I have way too many global variables. What methods to reduce these?
3. Any basic styling and convention issues?

All feedback is accepted, thanks in advance.

WARNING: this code may contain references to Dababy or Fortnite. (and UwUs)

Side note: highscores are saved on my website hosted with [pythonanywhere](https://pythonanywhere.com)

Now, for the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import requests
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
from tkinter import Widget
from tkinter import simpledialog

import applescript


def printArr():
    for row in arr:
        print(" ".join(str(cell) for cell in row))
        print("")


def createBoard(length, width):
    global arr

    arr = [[0 for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(width)]


def placeMine(x, y):
    ydim, xdim = len(arr), len(arr[0])

    arr[y][x] = ''

    if x != (xdim - 1):
        if arr[y][x + 1] != '':
            arr[y][x + 1] += 1  # center right

    if x != 0:
        if arr[y][x - 1] != '':
            arr[y][x - 1] += 1  # center left

    if (x != 0) and (y != 0):
        if arr[y - 1][x - 1] != '':
            arr[y - 1][x - 1] += 1  # top left

    if (y != 0) and (x != (xdim - 1)):
        if arr[y - 1][x + 1] != '':
            arr[y - 1][x + 1] += 1  # top right

    if y != 0:
        if arr[y - 1][x] != '':
            arr[y - 1][x] += 1  # top center

    if (x != (xdim - 1)) and (y != (ydim - 1)):
        if arr[y + 1][x + 1] != '':
            arr[y + 1][x + 1] += 1  # bottom right

    if (x != 0) and (y != (ydim - 1)):
        if arr[y + 1][x - 1] != '':
            arr[y + 1][x - 1] += 1  # bottom left

    if y != (ydim - 1):
        if arr[y + 1][x] != '':
            arr[y + 1][x] += 1  # bottom center


def createMap(mines, x, y):
    global arr

    createBoard(y, x)

    xlist = list(range(0, x))
    ylist = list(range(0, y))

    choiceslist = []

    for xchoice in xlist:
        for ychoice in ylist:
            choiceslist.append((xchoice, ychoice))

    if mines >= len(choiceslist):
        print('bro thats too many mines')
        sys.exit()

    for _ in range(mines):
        choice = random.choice(choiceslist)
        choiceslist.remove(choice)

        placeMine(choice[1], choice[0])


def subtractFlags():
    current_amount = flags.get()
    current_amount = current_amount.replace(('\u2691' + ' '), '')

    flags.set(f'\u2691 {int(current_amount) - 1}')


def addFlags():
    current_amount = flags.get()
    current_amount = current_amount.replace(('\u2691' + ' '), '')

    flags.set(f'\u2691 {int(current_amount) + 1}')


def openZeroNeighbors(first_widget, keep_going=True):
    openNeighbors(first_widget)
    global cellsopened

    info = first_widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    colorcodes = {1: 'blue',
                  2: 'green',
                  3: 'red',
                  4: 'purple',
                  5: 'maroon',
                  6: 'teal',
                  7: 'black',
                  8: 'white',
                  0: 'gray'}

    if keep_going is False:
        print('j')

    widget: Widget
    for widget in game.winfo_children():
        info = widget.grid_info()
        row1, col1 = info['row'], info['column']

        arritem = arr[row1][col1]

        neighbor = False

        if (row1 == row) and (abs(col1 - col) == 1):
            neighbor = True
        if (col1 == col) and (abs(row1 - row) == 1):
            neighbor = True
        if (abs(col1 - col) == 1) and (abs(row1 - row) == 1):
            neighbor = True

        if arritem != 0:  # and neighbor == False:
            continue

        elif arritem == 0 and neighbor is True:
            openNeighbors(first_widget)

        if neighbor is True and widget not in stack:
            if widget.cget('text') != str(arritem):
                cellsopened += 1
                widget.config(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[arritem])

            stack.add(widget)

            openZeroNeighbors(widget, keep_going=True)


def openNeighbors(widget):
    global cellsopened

    colorcodes = {1: 'blue',
                  2: 'green',
                  3: 'red',
                  4: 'purple',
                  5: 'maroon',
                  6: 'teal',
                  7: 'black',
                  8: 'white',
                  0: 'gray'}

    info = widget.grid_info()
    row1, col1 = info['row'], info['column']

    arritem = arr[row1][col1]
    if widget.cget('text') != str(arritem):
        widget.config(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[arritem])
        cellsopened += 1

    for widget in getNeighborsA(widget):
        info = widget.grid_info()
        row1, col1 = info['row'], info['column']

        arritem = arr[row1][col1]

        if widget.cget('text') != str(arritem):
            widget.config(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[arritem])
            cellsopened += 1


def getNeighbors(widget):
    global stack

    info = widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    neighbors = set([])

    for widget in game.winfo_children():
        info = widget.grid_info()
        row1, col1 = info['row'], info['column']

        neighbor = False

        if (row1 == row) and (abs(col1 - col) == 1):
            neighbor = True
        if (col1 == col) and (abs(row1 - row) == 1):
            neighbor = True
        if (abs(col1 - col) == 1) and (abs(row1 - row) == 1):
            neighbor = True

        if neighbor:
            neighbors.add(widget)

    return neighbors


def getNeighborsA(widget):
    ydim, xdim = len(arr), len(arr[0])
    info = widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    neighbors = []
    x = row
    y = col

    try:
        if x != (xdim - 1):
            if widgetlist[y][x + 1] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y][x + 1])  # center right

        if x != 0:
            if widgetlist[y][x - 1] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y][x - 1])  # center left

        if (x != 0) and (y != 0):
            if widgetlist[y - 1][x - 1] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y - 1][x - 1])  # top left

        if (y != 0) and (x != (xdim - 1)):
            if widgetlist[y - 1][x + 1] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y - 1][x + 1])  # top right

        if y != 0:
            if widgetlist[y - 1][x] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y - 1][x])  # top center

        if (x != (xdim - 1)) and (y != (ydim - 1)):
            if widgetlist[y + 1][x + 1] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y + 1][x + 1])  # bottom right

        if (x != 0) and (y != (ydim - 1)):
            if widgetlist[y + 1][x - 1] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y + 1][x - 1])  # bottom left

        if y != (ydim - 1):
            if widgetlist[y + 1][x] != '':
                neighbors.append(widgetlist[y + 1][x])  # bottom center

    except IndexError:
        pass

    return neighbors


def lclick(event):
    global cellsopened, first_click

    colorcodes = {1: 'blue',
                  2: 'green',
                  3: 'red',
                  4: 'purple',
                  5: 'maroon',
                  6: 'teal',
                  7: 'black',
                  8: 'white',
                  0: 'gray'}

    widget = event.widget

    info = widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    current = widget.cget('text')
    arritem = arr[row][col]

    if not first_click:
        global stack

        stack.add(widget)

        first_click = True
        while arritem != 0:
            createMap(mines=mines, x=dimensions[0], y=dimensions[1])
            arritem = arr[row][col]
        openZeroNeighbors(widget)

    if current != ' ':
        return

    if arritem == '':
        showMines()
        window.after(100, gameOver, False)
    elif arritem == 0:
        openZeroNeighbors(widget)
    else:
        widget.configure(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[arritem])
        cellsopened += 1

    window.after(69, checkWon)


def rclick(event):
    global widget
    widget = event.widget

    info = widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    current = widget.cget('text')

    current_amount = flags.get()
    current_amount = int(current_amount.replace(('\u2691' + ' '), ''))

    if current == ' ' and current_amount > 0:
        widget.configure(text='\u2691', fg='red')
        subtractFlags()
    elif current == '\u2691':
        widget.configure(text=' ')
        addFlags()


def showAll():
    colorcodes = {1: 'blue',
                  2: 'green',
                  3: 'red',
                  4: 'purple',
                  5: 'maroon',
                  6: 'teal',
                  7: 'black',
                  8: 'white',
                  0: 'gray'}
    for button in game.winfo_children():
        button: Widget
        info = button.grid_info()
        row, col = info['row'], info['column']

        current = button.cget('text')
        arritem = arr[row][col]

        if current == '\u2691':
            if arritem == '':
                button.configure(text=str(arritem), bg='dark green')
            else:
                button.configure(text=str(arritem),
                                 fg=colorcodes[arritem], bg='dark red')

        if arritem != '':
            button.configure(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[arritem])
        else:
            button.configure(text=str(arritem))

def showMines():
    colorcodes = {1: 'blue',
                  2: 'green',
                  3: 'red',
                  4: 'purple',
                  5: 'maroon',
                  6: 'teal',
                  7: 'black',
                  8: 'white',
                  0: 'gray'}

    for button in game.winfo_children():
        button: Widget
        info = button.grid_info()
        row, col = info['row'], info['column']

        current = button.cget('text')
        arritem = arr[row][col]

        if current == '\u2691':
            if arritem == '':
                button.configure(text=str(arritem), bg='dark green')
            else:
                button.configure(text=' ',
                                 fg=colorcodes[arritem], bg='dark red')

        if current != ' ':
            if arritem != '':
                button.configure(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[arritem])
        
        if arritem == '':
            button.configure(text='')

def changeGameButtons(gamearr):
    
    colorcodes = {1: 'blue',
                  2: 'green',
                  3: 'red',
                  4: 'purple',
                  5: 'maroon',
                  6: 'teal',
                  7: 'black',
                  8: 'white',
                  0: 'gray',
                  ' ': 'black',
                  '\u2691': 'red'}
                  
    for button in game.winfo_children():
        button: Widget
        info = button.grid_info()
        row, col = info['row'], info['column']

        arritem = gamearr[row][col]
        current = button.cget('text')

        if current == '\u2691':
            if arritem == '':
                button.configure(text=str(arritem), bg = 'light gray')
            else:
                button.configure(text=str(arritem),
                                 fg=colorcodes[int(arritem)], bg = 'light gray')

        if arritem != '':
            if arritem == ' ' or arritem == '\u2691':
                button.configure(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[(arritem)], bg = 'light gray')
            else:
                button.configure(text=str(arritem), fg=colorcodes[int(arritem)], bg = 'light gray')
        else:
            button.configure(text=str(arritem))

def toggleCheat():
    global cheat
    if cheat_activated:
        if not cheat:
            global gamearr

            gamearr = np.reshape(np.array([widget.cget('text') for widget in game.winfo_children()]), (dimensions[0], dimensions[1]))

            showAll()

            cheat = True
        
        else:
            changeGameButtons(gamearr)

            cheat = False

def turnOnCheat():
    global cheat_activated

    cheat_activated = True

def f5Clicked():
    global f5_clicked

    if cheat_on_time:
        f5_clicked = True

    if cheat_on_time and f6_clicked:
        turnOnCheat()

def f6Clicked():
    global f6_clicked

    if cheat_on_time and f5_clicked:
        f6_clicked = True
        
    if cheat_on_time and f5_clicked:
        turnOnCheat()

def addGameButtons():
    global zeros, widgetlist

    zeros = 0

    cols = dimensions[1]
    rows = dimensions[0]

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            button = tk.Label(game, width=1, text=' ', bg='light gray')

            # if arr[row][col] == 0:
            #                zeros += 1
            #                button.config(text = '0', fg = 'gray')

            widgetlist[col][row] = button

            button.grid(column=col, row=row, padx=2, pady=2)

            button.bind("<Button-1>", lclick)
            button.bind('<Button-2>', rclick)

def resetCheatOn():
    global cheat_on_time

    cheat_on_time = False

def timerUpdate():
    if first_click:
        current = timer.get()
        current = current.replace('⏱ ', '')

        timer.set(f'⏱ {round(eval(current) + 1)}')

    current = timer.get()
    current = current.replace('⏱ ', '')

    if current == '3':
        global cheat_on_time

        cheat_on_time = True

        window.after(1500, resetCheatOn)
    if not won:
        window.after(1000, timerUpdate)

def wonIn(time):
    if dimensions == (16, 30):
        diff = 'hard'
    elif dimensions == (13, 15):
        diff = 'med gium'
    elif dimensions == (9, 9):
        diff = 'easy'

    url = 'https://colding10.pythonanywhere.com/minesweeper'

    current = int(requests.post(url, data = {'command':'gethighscore', 'diff':diff}).text)

    if time < current:
        message = f'You beat the high score by {current-time} seconds!'

    else:
        message = f'You\'re {time-current} seconds behind the highscore of {current}!'
    return message

def gameOver(won):
    if not won:
        ans = messagebox.askyesno(
            message='You lost!\n\nDo you wish to play again?')
    else:
        current = timer.get()
        time = current.replace('⏱ ', '')
        msg = wonIn(int(time))

        ans = messagebox.askyesno(
            message=f'You won in {time} seconds!\n{msg}\n\nDo you wish to play again?')

    if ans:
        restart()

    else:
        window.destroy()
        sys.exit()


def checkWon():
    global won

    if cellsopened == (dimensions[0] * dimensions[1]) - mines - zeros:
        won = True
        gameOver(True)


def getCustomSize():
    dialog_text = 'set dimensions to display dialog "Enter dimensions (XxY)" default answer "2x2" with icon note ' \
                  'buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"\nset mines to display dialog "Enter ' \
                  'mines" default answer 0 with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button ' \
                  '"Continue"\n\nset mine to text returned of mines\nset dimes to text returned of ' \
                  'dimensions\n\nreturn {mine, dimes} '

    out = applescript.run(dialog_text)

    if out.err == '63:219: execution error: User canceled. (-128)':
        sys.exit()

    returned = out.out.split(', ')

    mines, dimes = returned[0], returned[1]

    try:
        mines = int(mines)

        if mines <= 0:
            raise ValueError

    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='Mines must be a positive integer!')
        sys.exit()

    dimes = dimes.split('x')

    err = 'no err les go DABABY uwu fortnite'

    if 'x'.join(dimes) == dimes:
        err = 'wrong dimensions format'

    else:
        try:
            dimensions = (int(dimes[0]), int(dimes[1]))

        except ValueError:
            err = 'not integers'

    if err == 'no err les go DABABY uwu fortnite':
        return dimensions, mines

    else:
        if err == 'wrong dimensions format':
            messagebox.showinfo(
                message='Wrong dimensions format! Please try again.')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(
                message='Dimensions not integers! Please try again.')
            sys.exit()


def getResp(buttons=[], text='', title='', default=0, cancel=0):
    d = simpledialog.SimpleDialog(window,
                                  text=text,
                                  buttons=buttons,
                                  default=default,
                                  cancel=cancel,
                                  title=title)

    return d.go()


def chooseDifficulty():
    dialog_text = 'set theDialogText to "Please select a difficulty:"\nset resp to display dialog theDialogText ' \
                  'buttons {"Cancel", "Custom", "Preset (Easy, Medium, Hard)"} cancel button "Cancel" default button ' \
                  '"Preset (Easy, Medium, Hard)"\nif button returned of resp = "Preset (Easy, Medium, ' \
                  'Hard)" then\n\treturn "preset"\nend if\nif button returned of resp = "Custom" then\n\treturn ' \
                  '"custom"\nend if '

    out = applescript.run(dialog_text)

    if out.err == '63:219: execution error: User canceled. (-128)':
        sys.exit()

    returned = out.out

    if returned == 'custom':
        dimes, mines = getCustomSize()

    if returned == 'preset':
        dialog_text = 'set theDialogText to "Please select a difficulty:"\nset resp to display dialog theDialogText ' \
                      'buttons {"Easy (9x9, 10 mines)", "Medium (13x15, 40 mines)", "Expert (16x30, 99 mines)"} ' \
                      'default button "Expert (16x30, 99 mines)"\nreturn button returned of resp '

        out = applescript.run(dialog_text)
        returned = out.out

        if returned == 'Expert (16x30, 99 mines)':
            dimes = (16, 30)
            mines = 99

        elif returned == 'Medium (13x15, 40 mines)':
            dimes = (13, 15)
            mines = 40

        elif returned == 'Easy (9x9, 10 mines)':
            dimes = (9, 9)
            mines = 10

    outres = {'dimensions': dimes, 'mines': mines}

    return outres


def main():
    global window, widgetlist, stack, game, flags, first_click, mines, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won, cheat, cheat_on_time, cheat_activated, f5_clicked, f6_clicked

    cheat_on_time = False
    cheat_activated = False
    cheat = False

    f5_clicked = False
    f6_clicked = False

    stack = set([])

    won = False
    first_click = False

    cellsopened = 0


    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('+1090+400')
    window.withdraw()
    window.bind('<F5>', lambda x: f5Clicked())
    window.bind('<F6>', lambda x: f6Clicked())

    # ========== CON0FIG SECTION ==========
    # mines = 99
    # dimensions = (16, 30)
    # ========== CONFIG SECTION ==========

    # ==============================
    difchoice = chooseDifficulty()

    mines = difchoice['mines']
    dimensions = difchoice['dimensions']
    # ==============================
    widgetlist = [[None for _ in range(dimensions[0])]
                  for _ in range(dimensions[1])]

    createMap(mines=mines, x=dimensions[0], y=dimensions[1])

    
    # center(window)
    # window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . middle')

    #iconimage = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'icon_png.png')
    #window.iconphoto(True, iconimage)

    window.deiconify()
    window.config(bg='gray')
    window.title('Minesweeper')
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.geometry('+1090+400')

    window.bind('<F19>', lambda x: toggleCheat())
    
    infobar = tk.Frame(bg='red')
    infobar.pack(side='top')

    game = tk.Frame()
    game.pack(side='bottom')

    flags = tk.StringVar()
    flags.set('\u2691' + f' {mines}')

    timer = tk.StringVar()
    timer.set('⏱' + ' 0')

    timecounter = tk.Label(infobar, bg='gray', textvariable=timer, width=5)
    timecounter.propagate(False)
    timecounter.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

    flagcounter = tk.Label(infobar, bg='gray', textvariable=flags)
    flagcounter.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')

    addGameButtons()

    window.after(10, timerUpdate)
    window.mainloop()


def restart():
    global window, game, flags, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won, cheat, cheat_on_time, cheat_activated, f5_clicked, f6_clicked

    window.destroy()

    del window, game, flags, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won, cheat, cheat_on_time, cheat_activated, f5_clicked, f6_clicked

    main()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    global window, game, flags, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won, cheat, cheat_on_time, cheat_activated, f5_clicked, f6_clicked

    main()


  [1]: https://pythonanywhere.com
```